# Jointly measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathbb{X})$ is a measure space.  The function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if $$\{x\in X:f(x)>y\}\in \mathbb{X}$$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}.$

I am familiar with this. But in a book (about analysis) I read about a jointly measurable function. There is not a definition. And I can not find any definition for this in Google.

**Question:** What is it? Why we need it? What were we missing in the concept of measurable functions so that we want to introduce a new concept?

EDIT: To be more precise I write the first sentence in the book where this term appears: "*For later use we now show that $\chi_{\{f>t\}}$ is a jointly measurable function of a and t*". What is it?

Comment: It is a measurable function  on a product space with a product $\sigma-$ algebra. Ref: Rudin's RCA.

Comment: If $A, T, Y$ are measure spaces and $f \colon A \times T \to Y$, then I would interpret $f(a, t)$ is a jointly measurable function of $a$ and $t$ to mean that $f$ is measurable using the product sigma algebra on $A \times T$.